# iBeacon Detect if person leaves grid

Tags: ios, swift, location, ibeacon

I wonder if someone has an idea of a better solution to solve an issue I am having.

I need my app to alert when a user break out of the grid of either the left or right side of a corridor or is about to

I have 4 beacons set out in the corner of a large thin straight corridor. Currently the user calibrates the app within this square - with a reading taken from each beacon.

Subsequent updates are taken from each beacon in order to give a position

The first way I thought to figure this out is to take a calibration - with this the user is in the corridor  - each beacons distance is added to create a total distance. If subsequent updates from each beacon show a higher distance in total the  user must have left the corridor.

```
func totalSize (l1:CGFloat, r1:CGFloat, l2:CGFloat, r2:CGFloat) -> CGFloat  {

    let bottomTotalDistance = l1 + r1
    let topTotalDistance = l2 + r2

    let completeTotal = CGFloat(bottomTotalDistance) + CGFloat(topTotalDistance)

    return completeTotal

}

self.currentTotal = self.totalSize(l1: CGFloat(self.leftBeaconOne!.currentPos!), r1: CGFloat(self.rightBeaconOne!.currentPos!), l2: CGFloat(self.leftBeaconTwo!.currentPos!), r2: CGFloat(self.rightBeaconTwo!.currentPos!))


  if currentTotal > self.total {

            if rightBeaconTwo!.currentPos! > leftBeaconTwo!.currentPos! || rightBeaconOne!.currentPos! > leftBeaconOne!.currentPos!{
                self.playLeftAlert()
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }else{
                self.playRightAlert()
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
```

Firstly this is pretty crude - and secondly the data from the beacons is proving to be inconsistent with up to 10 meters often being the difference (I thought there would be a steady flow of data that I could average out, however it seems like one call per second)

Secondly, is there an alternative with a combination of geolocation / steps / compass?

Unfortunately the corridor is only a couple of meters wide

Really appreciate any alternatives people can provide - the more practical the better :

Forgot to mention the app will always be in the foreground

Comment: This statement is key: "Unfortunately the corridor is only a couple of meters wide".  Detecting if somebody breaks off from the corridor is basically trying to get a +/- 1m position over its length with just four beacons.  I don't think bluetooth beacons can give you that kind of positioning accuracy.  You are right to ask for other technical solutions to replace or augment this.

Comment: @davidgyoung I suspected that was going to be the consensus -